# Creating a macro to perform default init

Tags: objective-c, macros

I have a lot of methods that repeat this simple boilerplate:

```
- (id)myObject {
    if(!_myObject) {
        self.myObject = [_myObject.class new];
    }
    return _myObject;
}
```

So I want to replace this with a simple macro:

```
#define default_init(instance) \
    if(!instance) instance = [instance.class new]; \
    return instance;
```

So that I would only have to call:

```
- (id)myObject {
        default_init(_myObject);
}
```

The above code currently compiles, but the issue is that the macro directly sets the instance variable's value. Instead, I'd like to call self.instance = value;

So instead of

```
if(!instance) instance = [instance.class new];
```

I'd like something like;

```
if(!instance) self.instance = [instance.class new];
```

But obviously the current code does not allow for this. How might I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this macro:

```
#define default_init(class, instance)      \
    if ( ! _##instance ) {                 \
        self.instance = [class new] ;      \
    }                                      \
    return _##instance
```

I was able to create this instance method:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) myObject {
    default_init(NSMutableArray, myObject) ;
}
```

I had to add a parameter defining the class, because `_myObject` is still `nil`, therefore `_myObject.class` is `nil`.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/1523962) and [this Cprogramming page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) recommend wrapping your multi-line macro in `do {...} while(0)`:

```
#define default_init(class, instance)          \
    do {                                       \
        if ( ! _##instance ) {                 \
            self.instance = [class new] ;      \
        }                                      \
        return _##instance ;                   \
    } while(0)
```

If you really wanted to, you could make a macro that defines the entire method:

```
#define default_getter(class, instance)        \
    - (class*) instance {                      \
        if ( ! _##instance ) {                 \
            self.instance = [class new] ;      \
        }                                      \
        return _##instance ;                   \
    }
```

And use it thusly:

```
default_getter(NSMutableArray, myObject)
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. Though just for the sake of the challenge, I wanted to figure out a way to do it without passing in a class - just the property. I've found a way to do this, but it does require an outside library. Check out the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a macro to build a getter method, I usually declare the property:

### Instance.h

```
@interface Instance : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray* myObject ;
@end
```

and override `- init` to initialize the property:

### Instance.m

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init] ;
    if ( self ) {
        self.myObject = [NSMutableArray new] ;
    }
    return self ;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to lazy-load

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my take on it.

Note: this was done just to see if it could be done. I don't think it would be a good idea to use this in shipping code.

First import `#import "EXTRuntimeExtensions.h"` from [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc). Then:

```
#define underize(name) _##name

#define property_type(property) \
    property_attr(property)->objectClass

#define property_attr(propertyName) \
    ext_copyPropertyAttributes(class_getProperty(self.class, # propertyName))

#define default_init(propertyName) \
    - (id)propertyName { \
       if(!underize(propertyName)) self.propertyName = [property_type(propertyName) new]; \
       return underize(propertyName); \
} \
```

Then say you have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *myArray;
```

You can do:

```
default_init(myArray);
```

And that creates a default getter.